# Time date calculations for different months in Teradata

Tags: date, time, teradata

How to  calculate following in Teradata:

```
Beginning Of Previous Month, 
End Of Previous Month, 
Beginning Of Six Months Ago, 
Beginning Of Twelve Months Ago
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Beginning Of Previous Month:    add_months(current_date - (extract(day from current_date)-1), -1) 
End Of Previous Month:                     current_date - (extract(day from current_date))
Beginning Of Six Months Ago:    add_months(current_date - (extract(day from current_date)-1), -6) 
Beginning Of Twelve Months Ago: add_months(current_date - (extract(day from current_date)-1), -12)
```

Depending on your release there might be some functions:

```
td_month_begin(add_months(current_date,-1))
last_day(add_months(current_date,-1))
```

Or you check your (hopefully) existing calendar table if those columns already exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot above statements worked perfectly for me.